# file created with 0 bytes during file upload in php

Tags: php, file-upload

Its kinda crazy, happening on my Ubuntu OS.

Trying to upload a file with the following script, Its creating a file with Zero bytes in the upload folder, Not sure whats going wrong. Can somebody have a look.

Here is my attached script

1. file1 - Name of the file input html element.
2. uploadbtn - name of the submit button.

Code:

```
// App Config 

$app_dir = '.';

$uploaddir = $app_dir . '/uploads/';

$filetype  = 'text/xml';
if ( isset($_POST['uploadbtn'] ) ){
        // Upload a file
        print_r( $_FILES );
        if ( !isset($_FILES['file1']['name']) || $_FILES['file1']['name'] == '' ) {
                echo 'No files uploaded, Pls upload a file';
                exit;
        }
        //print_r ( $_FILES ); 

        $filename = basename( $_FILES['file1']['name'] );

        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $filename ;

        if ($_FILES['file1']['type'] != $filetype ) {
                echo 'Sorry, your file was not of the ' . $filetype . ' mimetype (yours was ' . $_FILES['file1']['type'] . ').';
                exit;
        } // End filetype check 

        $upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile );

        if ( !$upload ){
                echo ' Uploading UNSUCCESSFUL ';
                print_r( $_FILES );
        } else {
                echo ' Uploading Successfulllllllllllllll';
        }

}
```

Comment: what did print_r($_FILES) show ?

Comment: file size as 0 and error also 0, It happens for some files, but for other files its working, this behaviour is not based on the filesize.